# C# getter setter default value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, getter-setter

How do you set default value for setter getter? I want to do some operations while setting the setter.

```
public bool spin {
    get { return this.spin; }
    set {
        if (value == false) this.spinBack = true;
        this.spin = value;
    }
}
private bool spinBack;
```

I tried this on Unity3D and got this error when trying to do so.

> StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack
>   overflow.

I tried just setting the getter and leave getter as default like so

```
public bool spin {
    get;
    set {
        if (value == false) this.spinBack = true;
        this.spin = value;
    }
}
private bool spinBack;
```

but I get this error

> 'spin.get' must have a body because it is not marked abstract, extern,
>   or partial

Comment: The getter and setter call themselves recursively.

Comment: I tried leaving getter body blank so it can call itself but I get this error: "'spin.get': not all code paths return a value"

Comment: This doesn't work that way. As soon as you implement _either_ of them, C# doesn't generate a backing field and you have to implement both (and a backing field).

Comment: So backing field is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StackOverflowException` is due to your `this.spin = value;` line which is recursively setting `spin`.

Use a backing field instead:

```
public bool Spin 
{
    get { return _spin; }
    set {
        if (value == false) this.spinBack = true;
        _spin = value;
    }
}

private bool _spin;
private bool spinBack;
```

Comment: I was thinking about using a backing field. I wanted to see if it's possible to use setters and getters on themselves.

Comment: @user1105430 OK, but as you've seen, it'll recurse and cause the above error. Is there any particular reason why can't use your own backing-field?

Comment: spinback appears useless. If value is false then it is set to true and if value is true, it will remain true. So it is false only until a true value comes in. Weird but why not...So you could just get it off and check for !Spin maybe.

Comment: Yeh, `spinback`'s function is unclear so have simply left it as is. A valid point, nonetheless. :)

Comment: I have no particular reason why I can't use backing field. I'm just wondering if C# allows you to do so without one. It' just to get a better understanding about getters and setters.

Comment: I didn't include the rest of the codes but "spinBack" does have a function. I simply use it as an example for this question. If curious, Instead of checking is "spin" is false and if rotation is not at original state for every Update() frame i simply made one flag ("spinBack") to check.

Comment: @user1105430 Properties like this are backed by a field. It's just that when you implement an auto-property it's generated by the compiler for you.